# Consider the function h where $h(x,y) = (x+y,x-y)$, $h : \mathbb N\times \mathbb N\to \mathbb N\times\mathbb N$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, functions

Is the function h onto and one to one? Prove this.

Online bonus question on a recent proofs quiz on the topic of one-to-one and onto functions. Gave me a bit of grief (the mapping stuff). Also consider this is a proofs class, much help would be appreciated.

I believe the answer would have to include something to do with x+y or x-y not being natural numbers? I could (most probably) be wrong though.

Please help.

Comment: It's not even defined with a range of $\mathbb N\times \mathbb N$, unless you mean the natural number subtraction where $2-3=0$.

Comment: so that means this function isn't even.. defined?

Comment: Right.  What is $h(2, 3)$?

Comment: @gunner check the question, maybe they want you to use $\mathbb{Z}$ instead of $\mathbb{N}$

Comment: However, it may have been a typo/oversight.  The function $h:  \Bbb{Z} \times \Bbb{Z} \to \Bbb{Z} \times \Bbb{Z}$ defined by the same formula makes sense and is one-to-one *but not onto.*

Comment: Wasn't this asked yesterday or two days ago??

Answer (score 0):

So, the question doesn't make much sense if we are talking about $\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}$ since it's not defined everywhere. Let's pretend you said $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$ instead of $\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}$.

Let $h(x,y)=(a,b)$. Can we find such values for $x,y$? Are they unique? The answer is yes, they are given by $(\frac{a+b}{2},\frac{a-b}{2})$. You get this by solving the system of equations $x+y=a,x-y=b$. Uniqueness comes from this being a linear system of 2 variables and 2 equations

Answer (score 0):

$h$ is one to one becouse if $h(x,y)=h(a,b)$ then $(x+y,x-y)=(a+b,a-b)$, then summing the equations we obtain $2x=2a\Rightarrow x=a$ and subtraing we obtain $2y=2b \Rightarrow y=b$, i.e., $(x,y)=(a,b)$.

But $h$ is not onto becouse $\not \exists (x,y)\in \mathbb{N\times N}$ such that $h(x,y)=(1,1)$, for example. Indeed, if $h(x,y)=(1,1)$ then $x+y=1$ and $x-y=1$, and summing the equations we obtain $2x=1$, i.e., $x=\frac{1}{2}$ but $\frac{1}{2}\not \in \mathbb{N}$.